# How to combine 2 models into 1 for ObjectListView?

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I have the following model, which is central model and used in ObjectListView

```
Cells(List)
  Number (same as Cell Number)
  Status
  Lots of properties
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I also have the following model, which is used in other ObjectListView.

```
Tests (List)
  Cell Number
  Enabled
  Warning
  Passes
  Name
```

It looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to modify first model model to feed both ObjectListViews in order to avoid redundancy:

Ideally the new model would look like this:

```
Cells (List)
  Number (same as Cell Number)
  Status
  Lots of properties
  Tests (List)
```

But then it's not clear how to feed it to second ObjectListView.

Question - how to combine these 2 models in order to be able feed OLV to have the result like on screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no way for the ObjectListView to generate **multiple row** from a **single model object**.

You'll need to generate the IENUMERABLE of **Tests** at one point.

You can let the OLV do this by iterating the list of **Cells** and adding (olv.addObjects) each ienumerable of **tests** to the secondary ObjectListView.

Comment: So I anyway merged those 2 models into 1 model, but for second OLV I've used `centralModel.SelectMany(...)`.